# A column ID occurred more than once in the specification?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am getting this error message when using EF 4.1 code first approach with Sql compact 4. I don't see any model who has id column more than one so i have no idea why this error occured. What can cause this error ?

Edit : I want to specifiy few extra things. Database creating is success but model creating is not. And Exception has been thrown from sqlce methods.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your Model for us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue stems from a SQL query that returns two or more columns that have an identical name. SQL will handle exact duplicate names on columns with no problem but c# will puke errors all over like this one.

example situation:

```
TableA
  int Id
  varchar Name

TableB
  int Id
  int A_Id
  varchar Name


SELECT A.*,
       B.Name
FROM TableA A

INNER JOIN TableB 
   ON B.A_Id = A.Id
```

The Id and Name columns would be duplicated and cause an exception with EF

Comment: I got it. Inherited models has same named properties.

Comment: @Freshblood Sorry I didn't get back to you. I figured inheritance might be the cause but failed to mention this scenario at the time. I am glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be caused when the migration code is  not update to date. This usally occurs when the executing the Add-Mirgration  muliple times. Run the following command instead:

```
Add-Migration <migration-name> -force
```