# A column ID occurred more than once in the specification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Recently i've picked up my EF 4.1 / MVC 3 project again and started building in actual frontend capabilities.

Now i'm developing a "simple"  message system but upon going to that page i get the error as stated in the title

**EDIT**

It creates the database just not the models.

Stack trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    ASP._Page_Views_Inbox_Index_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Development\MVC\DOCCL\Views\Inbox\Index.cshtml:18
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +222
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +295    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +324
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +91    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +19
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +48
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7 
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
>   +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9478661    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +178

InnerException :
{"A column ID occurred more than once in the specification."}

The recently added code is.

Controller:

```
//
// GET: /Inbox/Index/5/1
public ActionResult Index(int? Id, int Page = 1)
{
    try
    {
        const int pageSize = 10;
        var messages = from m in horseTracker.Messages
                        where m.ReceiverId.Equals(Id)
                        select m;

        var paginatedMessages = new PaginatedList<Message>(messages, Page, pageSize);

        return View(paginatedMessages);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

Models

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Boolean Read { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Can't create a message without a user")]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick a recipient")]
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "E-Mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string EMail { get; set; }

    //Races
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Messages)
    .WithRequired(m => m.Receiver)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.ReceiverId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Anyone have a clue on why i might be getting that error?
Before i added these classes it was working fine.

Comment: Showing possible inner exceptions and the stack trace could help.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750742/a-column-id-occurred-more-than-once-in-the-specification

Comment: i posted the inner exception Slauma. As for that topic no it does not. i use the same technique in various other spots for example i have a horse class which has a dam and a sire both of type horse and they don't complain about the Id's at all. it just seems very strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Message Model, Id is not nullable, but your action allows nulls, EF cant match these two types up in the where clause in your query & throw an exception.

Comment: That was exactly it thank you so much. ran into another issue but it's a step further.

Comment: I had 2 email fields in the user model. once i removed those the page rendered fine.